# Pull back values from field B where the data in field A is the max

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a report in Oracle SQL that brings back a list of all the times a plot of grass has been cut in the current financial year.

This gives me the following information:

```
Central Asset ID         Grass Cut?        Grass Cut Reason          Cut Date


1234                     Yes              Yes - Grass Cut            14/04/2023


1234                     No               No - Ground waterlogged    28/4/2023
```

What I would like to do is bring back the central asset id field and the grass cut reason field where the cut date is the latest - in the example above I would like to bring back

Central Asset ID  1234
Grass Cut Reason "No - Ground waterlogged"

into a report that shows the most  recent grass cut reason for each plot.

This is my existing code

```
select
feature.central_asset_id,
case
when observe_parm_opt.obs_parm_opt_name like 'Yes%' then 'Cut' 
when observe_parm_opt.obs_parm_opt_name like 'No%' then 'Not Cut'   
when observe_parm_opt.obs_parm_opt_name is NULL  then '' 
else ''     
end as grasscut,
Max(observe_parm_opt.obs_parm_opt_name) as Grass_Cut_Reason,
max(inspection_feature.feature_insp_date) as Insp_Date

from
feature
inner join inspection_feature on inspection_feature.site_code = feature.site_code and inspection_feature.plot_number = feature.plot_number
inner join insp_condition on inspection_feature.insp_batch_no = insp_condition.insp_batch_no and
inspection_feature.site_code = insp_condition.site_code and inspection_feature.plot_number = insp_condition.plot_number

inner join observe_type on insp_condition.observe_type_key = observe_type.observe_type_key
inner join observe_parameter on observe_type.obs_parm_code = observe_parameter.obs_parm_code
inner join observe_parm_opt on observe_parameter.obs_parm_code = observe_parm_opt.obs_parm_code
inner join central_site on inspection_feature.site_code = central_site.site_code
inner join feature_type on feature.feature_type_code = feature_type.feature_type_code

where
insp_condition.grade_code = observe_parm_opt.obs_parm_opt_code and observe_type.observe_type_code = 'G003' and
inspection_feature.feature_insp_date >= TO_DATE('30/03/2022','DD/MM/YYYY') and
feature.feature_type_code in ('G005')

group by
feature.central_asset_id,
observe_parm_opt.obs_parm_opt_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `MAX` function, try with `ROW_NUMBER` analytic one which "sorts" data per each `central_asset_id` by `feature_insp_date` in descending order so that the most recent rows are placed *on top* of the list, i.e. their `rn` column equals 1.

Your current query (with such an addition, and without `group by` clause as you don't need it any more) is then a CTE (or a subquery; doesn't really matter) and you'd finally fetch rows that ranked as the highest.

Something like this:

```
with temp as(
   select
   feature.central_asset_id,
   case
   when observe_parm_opt.obs_parm_opt_name like 'Yes%' then 'Cut' 
   when observe_parm_opt.obs_parm_opt_name like 'No%' then 'Not Cut'   
   when observe_parm_opt.obs_parm_opt_name is NULL  then '' 
   else ''     
   end as grasscut,
   observe_parm_opt.obs_parm_opt_name as Grass_Cut_Reason,
   inspection_feature.feature_insp_date as Insp_Date,
   --
   row_number() over (partition by feature.central_asset_id order by inspection_feature.feature_insp_date desc) rn
   from
   feature
   inner join inspection_feature on inspection_feature.site_code = feature.site_code and inspection_feature.plot_number = feature.plot_number
   inner join insp_condition on inspection_feature.insp_batch_no = insp_condition.insp_batch_no and
   inspection_feature.site_code = insp_condition.site_code and inspection_feature.plot_number = insp_condition.plot_number

   inner join observe_type on insp_condition.observe_type_key = observe_type.observe_type_key
   inner join observe_parameter on observe_type.obs_parm_code = observe_parameter.obs_parm_code
   inner join observe_parm_opt on observe_parameter.obs_parm_code = observe_parm_opt.obs_parm_code
   inner join central_site on inspection_feature.site_code = central_site.site_code
   inner join feature_type on feature.feature_type_code = feature_type.feature_type_code
   --
   where
   insp_condition.grade_code = observe_parm_opt.obs_parm_opt_code and observe_type.observe_type_code = 'G003' and
   inspection_feature.feature_insp_date >= TO_DATE('30/03/2022','DD/MM/YYYY') and
   feature.feature_type_code in ('G005')
)
select central_asset_id, grasscut, grass_cut_reason, insp_date
from temp
where rn = 1
```